# Rotate image during the Upload only with JPEG from IOs

Tags: ios, image, codeigniter, upload

I have a problem with the images .JPEG, I upload the image but display with rotate 90º(autorotate the image), only happening with images from IOS.

Anyone Fix for the library Upload or how fix this with only images from IOS?

Comment: are you using ImagePicker?

Comment: the library upload.php

Comment: @NARTONIC rahul wants to ask you are you using image from camera to upload on you server.